# Obscure question titles

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I came across the question *[Can't understand this way to calculate the square of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828822/cant-understand-this-way-to-calculate-the-square-of-a-number)* which has a healthy number of views answers and upvotes.

It seems to me it really isn't about computing the square of a number. Rather, it's about arcane side affects of pointer arithmetic.

I'm curious why some questions get singled out for rigorous screening, downvoting, etc. for poor title phrasing, off topic content whatever, and others don't. For what it's worth, I thought the various responses were fascinating, but it did leave me wondering what this is all for. It also reinforced my fear and loathing of C and its offsprings.

Comment: Good answers can make a decent/bad question a great question.

Comment: Chicken / egg?  I read somewhere here that a consideration for question titles is whether they help people skimming through lists of questions land on relevant answers.  BTW its probably unfair to pick on this question, but it did jump out at me while looking through posts for pointers to improve my own as an example of a suspicion I have that some posts get more aggressively moderated than others.  MAybe just human nature at work.

Comment: That's true, but sometimes people are sitting on a good answer and just looking for an excuse to put it somewhere; it's hard to guess why people would answer a given question.

Answer (score 2):

This question is crosslinked from a popular codegolf question where the exact bizarre code appears. Therefore, we get a lot of traffic here from codegolf to that question. Therefore, it's going to get lots of votes.

I don't like the title very much due to unreferenced this, but I can't think of a good way to fix it so I'm leaving it.